# sql update function with a left join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having some trouble writing a sql update function. I Have a table of quotes and a second table of products associated with those quotes. I am trying to set all the statuses of quotes with certain $ values based on the products. I cant seem to format this query correctly (code below). I know code is limited to 1 ID currently trying to test with 1 before I remove that portion.

```
sqlStringUpdate = "UPDATE fq SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5 From factQuote fq (LEFT JOIN FactQuoteProduct as fqp on fq.spQuoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID) " & _
"WHERE fq.spQuoteID = 4844 and ((sum(fqp.ItemTotal) <2000 and fq.quoteDate < #" & firstset & "#) or ( fq.bu=3401 and sum(fqp.ItemTotal) <10000 and fq.quoteDate < #" & secondset & "# ) or ( fq.bu>3401 and sum(fqp.ItemTotal) <10000 and fq.quoteDate < #" & secondset & "#));"
```

error code: error 3075(syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '5 Left JOIN factQUotePRoduct as fqp on fq.spQUoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID')

Comment: So what's the error you're getting or the how are the results you're getting not matching what you're expecting?  I'm guessing you're getting an error because that UPDATE ... SET ... FROM is incorrect syntax.  You're updating a table and setting a value on a condition so usually it's UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE.

Comment: the error is syntax missing operator

Comment: Is the carriage return in your actual code? You forgot the `_`, and with the double quotes you'll have to add `&` to the beginning of line 2. If not, the missing operator might be a semi-colon at the end of line 1, because that's all you are saving to `sqlStringUpdate`.

Comment: no its there i somehow stupidly managed to copy paste without it

Comment: If you're just looking to join to be able to use the data from FactQuoteProduct in your where clause then you can join after the update and then do your set immediately after that.  So UPDATE factQuote LEFT JOIN FactQuoteProduct ON ... SET ... WHERE ....

Comment: thx that did the trick apparently aggregate functions arent allowed in sql but I can rewrite that easy

Answer (score 0):

first problem is the LEFT JOIN should not be in parenthesis.

second problem, you need to calculate the aggregate before the update, you can solve this using CTE syntax, try something like this:

```
;with
fqp as (
    select fk_spQuoteID, sum(ItemTotal) sum_ItemTotal
    from FactQuoteProduct 
    group by fk_spQuoteID
)
UPDATE fq SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5 
From factQuote fq 
LEFT JOIN fqp on fq.spQuoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID
WHERE fq.spQuoteID = 4844 
and (
    (fqp.sum_ItemTotal <2000 and fq.quoteDate < @firstset) 
    or ( fq.bu=3401 and fqp.sum_ItemTotal <10000 and fq.quoteDate < @secondset ) 
    or ( fq.bu>3401 and fqp.sum_ItemTotal <10000 and fq.quoteDate < @secondset )
    );
```

if you are not common with CTE syntax you can use nested select like this:

```
UPDATE fq SET fq.spQuoteStatus = 5 
From factQuote fq 
LEFT JOIN (
    select fk_spQuoteID, sum(ItemTotal) sum_ItemTotal
    from FactQuoteProduct 
    group by fk_spQuoteID
) as fqp on fq.spQuoteID=fqp.fk_spQuoteID
WHERE fq.spQuoteID = 4844 
and (
    (fqp.sum_ItemTotal <2000 and fq.quoteDate < @firstset) 
    or ( fq.bu=3401 and fqp.sum_ItemTotal <10000 and fq.quoteDate < @secondset ) 
    or ( fq.bu>3401 and fqp.sum_ItemTotal <10000 and fq.quoteDate < @secondset )
    );
```

this should do the trick